# CreateRemoteThread access denied

Tags: c++, access-denied

I am trying to create a remote thread on the "notepad.exe" process using CreateRemoteThread() but i am getting error code 5 "Access-Denied". I tried enabling debug permissions due to the intergrity level being "High" but that did not do the trick. I know my function works since i tested it on a simple console app and it created it successfully. So there seems to be some sort of issue aside from if not also debug privileges that im missing.

I apologize for not posting the code, i currently dont have access to it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This happens when there is an architecture mismatch between your application (32 bits) and the target application (64 bits) on a 64 bits OS. The solution is to compile your program in 64 bits mode (but then of course it won't be able to access 32 bits processes any more, it's either/or).

This may or may not be your situation (hard to tell with so little information) but it's worth mentioning anyway, hence this answer instead of a mere comment.

Comment: Ya after reading a few more posts im beggining to think that may be the cause. I do run Win7 64bit.